# onclick function sometimes doesn't fire its event

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a problem that occurs in my application.
When a user clicks on a `div` that should fire an event, sometimes (about ~1/10) nothing occurs - the `onclick` event isn't fired, the other times everything goes well. This is very strange...

In a short code I can replicate that problem:

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .links:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="init_panel" style="visibility:visible; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"></span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function init_match(){
    alert("in init_match()");
    //...
  }
  var flag=true;
  function loop(){
    if (flag){
        var div = document.getElementById("init_panel");
        var HTML = "<div class='links' onclick='init_match();'><font color='black'><b>new match!</b></font></div><br />";
        if (div.innerHTML!=HTML){
            div.innerHTML=HTML;
        }
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
    else{
        div.innerHTML="";
    }
  }
  loop();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to change the content of a series of divs and the corresponding links with JavaScript; that's why I need a code similar to that one.
I hope someone cans clarify how to avoid that problem in the events, and I appreciate very much any help!

*EDIT to add the following info:*

I've added the following js code:

```
document.onclick = my_handler;
function my_handler() {
    alert("the document was clicked!");
}
```

The result is: the same times that the other onclick fails, this document.onclick fails, too. This is very weird! I would like to update the contents of the divs, without having fails on their onclick events...

The latest version of the jsfiddle where this bug can be seen is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/grSDs/3/

The success & failure rates seam to change for different browsers and also according to if the script is running directly or if it's running through the jsfiddle interface (with different situations having a success rate from ~90% to ~0%).

Comment: `<spam>`? is this a typo?

Comment: I think you're looking for <span> for starters.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a jsFiddle (or similar) of your issue, to help others more easily provide an answer. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I meant <span> (so I updated that tag in the code), but if I use <div> instead of <span> the problem is the same.

Comment: any console errors ? and maybe an onload is needed

Comment: There are no errors with opera's inspect element tool, neither with firebug in the console. The loop() function is called when the code arrives the line loop(), so it seems that an onload isn't necessary.

Comment: Its jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/siluaty/grSDs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after many attempts, I've found a solution:

I had to replace the line:

```
var HTML = "<div class='links' onclick='init_match();'><font color='black'><b>new match!</b></font></div><br />";
```

by:

```
var HTML = "<div class=\"links\" onclick=\"init_match();\"><font color=\"black\"><b>new match!</b></font></div><br>";
```

because the innerHTML of that div is automatically changed to the 2nd line when I insert the 1st line. So, when the code was comparing my HTML (the 1st string) with the automatically generated div.innerHTML (the 2nd string), the program was refreshing the div.innerHTML even when it should be quiet, breaking the link sometimes.

The logic of the code was correct, and that error had a very stange behavior, and a non logic solution.

It's weird the fact that javascript changes `<br />` to `<br>` (why?) and that it also changes the quotes.